# How to send myself an email notification when a suds job is done?

Tags: python, email, suds

I'm learning to use `suds` in a python script to send SQL queries to a database. I'd like to able to send myself an email when the query job is finished (it has a job ID so I'm able to check its status). How do I do that?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? `email` is a standard Python module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html. If it does not do what you need it to do, then you need to add why.

Comment: I'm able to get it to work now! Thanks to both for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you send an email via python just fill in the blanks and input it to your code:

```
import smtplib

content = ("Content to send")

mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)

mail.ehlo()

mail.starttls()

mail.login('your_email@gmail.com','123your_password')

mail.sendmail('your_email@gmail.com','destination_email@gmail.com',content) 

mail.close()

print("Sent")
```

(you dont have to use gmail as most addresses will still work through the gmail smtp)

Comment: you might want to use this for `content`, `content = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subject, text)` and make `subject` and `text` the subject and content of email

Answer (score 1):

If email is not required, you can also send chat messages to yourself.

Two projects achieving this :

- Nimrod, for Facebook Messenger : https://www.nimrod-messenger.io/
- Telegram Middleman, for Telegram : https://github.com/n1try/telegram-middleman-bot

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a Python decorator for this purpose. You can realize it in one line.

https://github.com/Wenzhi-Ding/py_reminder

```py
from py_reminder import monitor

@monitor('SQL Query of xxx')
def query(sql):
    ...send your query...

query()
```

Once this function finishes / or is caught an error, you will get an email notification with some brief information.